# Is it possible to iteratively find combinations of records that sum to zero. And how to accomplish?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to scrape through a table of records and find all combinations that sum to zero on a number field. First finding all 3-way matches, then 4-way, then 5-way and so on. Each time a combination is found it should be removed from the pool of candidates.

A simplified example:

| key_id | amount |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| B | -12 |
| C | 20 |
| D | 2 |
| E | -2 |
| F | -8 |
| G | 7 |
| H | -7 |
| I | -10 |
| J | -18 |

The first combination found is [A, B, D]. That combinations is written to a dataframe and removed from the population for consideration.

It finds no more 3-way combinations so it moves on to 4-way.

The first combination found is [C, E, F, I]

Suppose that is all it finds the final result set is;

| key_id |
| --- |
| [A, B, D] |
| [C, E, F, I] |

Using itertools this is what I have been able to write so far. Not sure how well it would scale. Also don't know how I would write it so that the combinations are removed each time. And also iterate through 3-way, 4-way, through n-way

```
from itertools import combinations

sourceDF = sourceDF.withColumn("index",F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id()))-1)

res = [ [','.join(j),sourceDF.amount[np.in1d(sourceDF.key_id, j)].sum()] for i in sourceDF.index + 1 for j in combinations(sourceDF.key_id,i)]
combDF = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['combinations', 'amt_sum'])
combDF = combDF [(combDF .amt_sum + amount) == 0]
```

I realize it is computationally a heavy task, which is why I am trying to figure out how to make it iterative to remove the combinations each time. Would it be possible to create some "commit points" to write the data out to a table in smaller batches? I could also run the 3-way, 4-way etc as sequential batch jobs.

Comment: Wouldn't the results depend on the order in which you look?

Comment: Since no combination of entirely positive or entirely negative numbers can ever sum to zero you may be able to narrow the search space accordingly.

Comment: The requirement that you remove any matching entries is an odd one.  That invalidates the rest of the list of combinations.  I think you would have to remove them, and then restart that set from the beginning.

Comment: Agreed, it is not ideal to only show a value in one possible combination. I was trying to think of the least-bad solution. My plan is to present the user with a "possible matching combination". They can then either accept or reject it. If it is rejected it goes back in the pool and I try to find the next possible combination

Answer (score 0):

you could make a function that tracks the combinations in a set, adding values to all previous combinations to form new ones.  By sorting the numbers in each combination, the set will automatically eliminate duplicates.

```
def zeroSum(values):
    combos = {tuple()}
    for v in values:
        newCombos = { tuple(sorted((*c,v))) for c in combos } - combos
        yield from filter(lambda c:sum(c)==0,newCombos)
        combos.update(newCombos)
```

output:

```
amounts = [10,12,20,2,-2,-8,7,-7,-10,-18]
print(*zeroSum(amounts),sep="\n")

(-2, 2)
(-8, -2, 10)
(-7, 7)
(-7, -2, 2, 7)
(-8, -7, -2, 7, 10)
(-10, 10)
(-10, -2, 12)
(-10, -2, 2, 10)
(-10, -8, -2, 20)
(-10, -7, 7, 10)
(-10, -7, -2, 7, 12)
(-10, -7, -2, 2, 7, 10)
(-10, -8, -7, -2, 7, 20)
(-18, -2, 20)
(-18, -7, -2, 7, 20)
(-18, -10, -2, 10, 20)
(-18, -10, -7, -2, 7, 10, 20)
```

*[EDIT]*

Here is a variant that lets you control the size of the output and produces key combinations rather than numbers.  It will start at the specified size and increase the size after exhausting combinations of the smaller size:

```
from itertools import product

def zeroSum(D,size):
    R = dict()
    R.update( (v,R.get(v,[])+[k]) for k,v in D.items() )
    combos = {tuple()}
    foundMore = 1
    while foundMore:
        foundMore = 0
        for v in D.values():
            newCombos = {tuple(sorted((*c,v))) for c in combos if len(c)<size}
            for combo in newCombos - combos:
                if sum(combo) == 0 and len(combo)==size:
                    for keyCombo in product(*map(R.get,combo)):
                        if len(set(keyCombo))==size:
                            yield sorted(keyCombo)
                            foundMore = 1
                if sum(combo) == 0 or len(combo)<size:
                    combos.add(combo)
        size += 1
```

It uses the same approach as above but sets a limit on a specific size.  The "key_ids" are computed after obtaining a unique value combinations (using an inverted dictionary and itertools.product).  This avoids storing combinations of keys that have the same value in the combos set which would significantly increase its size when duplicate values are present.

output:

```
amounts = {"A":10,"B":-12,"C":20,"D":2,"E":-2,"F":-8,"G":7,
           "H":-7,"I":-10,"J":-18}        
            
print(*zeroSum(amounts,3),sep="\n")
['A', 'B', 'D']
['A', 'E', 'F']
['B', 'C', 'F']
['C', 'E', 'J']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'J']
['B', 'C', 'D', 'I']
['A', 'D', 'E', 'I']
['D', 'E', 'G', 'H']
['C', 'E', 'F', 'I']
['A', 'G', 'H', 'I']
['A', 'B', 'D', 'G', 'H']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'I']
['A', 'C', 'E', 'I', 'J']
['B', 'C', 'F', 'G', 'H']
['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
['A', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
['C', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'J']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'G', 'H', 'J']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'J']
['B', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'H', 'I']
['A', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I']
['C', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'I']
['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
['A', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'J']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
```

Because this is a generator, it will allow you to go through the combinations one by one and stop once a suitable one has been selected:

```
for combo in zeroSum(amounts,3):
    if input(f"select {combo} ? (y/n) ") == "y": break

select ['A', 'B', 'D'] ? (y/n) n
select ['A', 'E', 'F'] ? (y/n) n
select ['B', 'C', 'F'] ? (y/n) n
select ['C', 'E', 'J'] ? (y/n) n
select ['A', 'B', 'C', 'J'] ? (y/n) n
select ['B', 'C', 'D', 'I'] ? (y/n) y
```

*Note that, if there aren't many duplicate values in the amounts, a brute force approach using itertools (see Scott Boston's answer) will be more efficient.  Actually i'm not even sure this is any better than brute force even with duplicate amounts.*

Comment: The solution does not need to be in pandas. This is not exactly what I am after as I am specifically looking for the "key_ids" for each combination. And I want to be able to specify the number values (3, 4 etc) that should net to zero. Scaling to larger sets is the real enemy here as you can already see how many combinations get generated by just a few rows of data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let use powersets recipe from itertools and list_comprehension:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

[df.reindex(e)['key_id'].to_list() for e in powerset(df.index) if df.reindex(e)['amount'].sum() == 0]
```

Output:

```
[[],
 ['A', 'I'],
 ['D', 'E'],
 ['G', 'H'],
 ['A', 'B', 'D'],
 ['A', 'E', 'F'],
 ['B', 'C', 'F'],
 ['C', 'E', 'J'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'J'],
 ['A', 'D', 'E', 'I'],
 ['A', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
 ['B', 'C', 'D', 'I'],
 ['C', 'E', 'F', 'I'],
 ['D', 'E', 'G', 'H'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'I'],
 ['A', 'B', 'D', 'G', 'H'],
 ['A', 'C', 'E', 'I', 'J'],
 ['A', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
 ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
 ['B', 'C', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
 ['C', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'J'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'J'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'G', 'H', 'J'],
 ['A', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
 ['B', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
 ['C', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'I'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
 ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
 ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'J'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']]
```

And to look for specific lengths of results you can use this with the walrus operator:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))


n = 3
[dc['key_id'].to_list() for e in powerset(df.index) if (dc:=df.reindex(e))['amount'].sum() == 0 and dc.shape[0] == n]
n = 4
[dc['key_id'].to_list() for e in powerset(df.index) if (dc:=df.reindex(e))['amount'].sum() == 0 and dc.shape[0] == n]
```

For n=3 output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'E', 'F'], ['B', 'C', 'F'], ['C', 'E', 'J']]
```

for n=4 output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'J'],
 ['A', 'D', 'E', 'I'],
 ['A', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
 ['B', 'C', 'D', 'I'],
 ['C', 'E', 'F', 'I'],
 ['D', 'E', 'G', 'H']]
```

Comment: Brilliant! I was playing with the powerset recipe myself yesterday but could only return the index values by the time I gave up for the day. One edit that greatly speeds things up is to use `range(n+1)` instead of `range(len(s)+1))` in the powerset recipe. That way it only iterates up to n instead of trying to find the combinations > n, just to have those combinations removed again. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
pd.DataFrame([[j for i in list(itertools.combinations(df.to_records(index=False),n)) for j,k in [list(zip(*i))] if sum(k) == 0] for n in range(3,8)])
```

or

```
pd.DataFrame([[[j[0] for j in i] for i in itertools.combinations(df.apply(tuple,axis=1),n) if sum([j[-1] for j in i]) == 0] for n in range(3,8)])
```

or

```
r = df.to_records(index=False).tolist()

pd.DataFrame([[list(a[0]) for a in [[j for j in zip(*i)] for i in itertools.combinations(r,n)] if sum(a[-1])==0] for n in range(3,8)])
```

Output:

```
                       0                      1                      2                      3                   4                5                6
0              [A, B, D]              [A, E, F]              [B, C, F]              [C, E, J]                None             None             None
1           [A, B, C, J]           [A, D, E, I]           [A, G, H, I]           [B, C, D, I]        [C, E, F, I]     [D, E, G, H]             None
2        [A, B, C, F, I]        [A, B, D, G, H]        [A, C, E, I, J]        [A, E, F, G, H]     [B, C, D, E, F]  [B, C, F, G, H]  [C, E, G, H, J]
3     [A, B, C, D, E, J]     [A, B, C, G, H, J]     [A, D, E, G, H, I]     [B, C, D, G, H, I]  [C, E, F, G, H, I]             None             None
4  [A, B, C, D, E, F, I]  [A, B, C, F, G, H, I]  [A, C, E, G, H, I, J]  [B, C, D, E, F, G, H]                None             None             None
```